# What is ((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c; mean in c?

Tags: c, casting, void-pointers, pointer-arithmetic, memset

```
void    *ft_memset(void *b, int c, size_t len)
{
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < len)
    {
        ((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return (b);
}
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to give more detail about what you're wondering about. Is it the cast? Is it what the cast is doing? Is it the indexing? Is it how array-indexing can be used with pointers? Is it the assignment? Something else?

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The cast is because the compiler can't index a `void*` pointer.

Comment: While we're at it, may as well ask, "what does the function `return()` return?"

Comment: It means, cast `b` to a pointer of unsigned characters and assign the ith character (`char` elements that is `i` characters away from `b`) to the value `c`.

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to understand if we rewrite `((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c;` as `unsigned char *p = b; p[i] = c;`?

Answer (score 2):

You could write for example

```
b[i] = c;
```

However the dereferencing the pointer of the type `void *`

```
void *b
```

yields an object of the incomplete type `void`. So the compiler will issue an error.

So at first the pointer of the type void * is cast to the pointer type unsigned char * and then the subscript operator is applied

```
((unsigned char *)b)[i] = c;
```

Now as the type unsigned char is a complete type the compiler can use the pointer arithmetic in the evaluation of the subscript operator.

Pay attention to that the subscript operator is evaluated like

```
*( ( unsigned char * )p + i ) = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pointers to void](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void)

> Pointer to object of any type can be implicitly converted to pointer to void (optionally const or volatile-qualified), and vice versa.
>
> Pointers to void are used to pass objects of unknown type, which is common in generic interfaces.

When it comes to your question, it is releveant what your function does. As the name suggests, the parameter `b` points to a block of memory of size `len` (bytes), which has to be filled with a specific value, described by `c`.

In order to set each byte of the block of memory, we have to be able to access each byte individually. We achieve that by casting the pointer to an `unsigned char`, the 'byte' type in C.

- cast generic pointer to a pointer to type `unsigned char`:
  `((unsigned char *)b)`
- access the ith element in that array:
  `[i]`

Equivalent to:

```
unsigned char *bytes = (unsigned char*) b;
for (size_t i=0; i < len; ++i)
    bytes[i] = c;
```